# Cálculo de horas com Java 8

Tags: java, java-ee, java-8

Eu estava fazendo uns testes com o java 8, e estava tentando calcular a diferença entre horas de duas datas. Eu consegui de três jeitos, porém, não sei qual seria o mais correto e gostaria da ajuda de vocês.

```java
 LocalDateTime t1 = LocalDateTime.of(2014, Month.NOVEMBER, 25, 8, 23);  
 LocalDateTime t2 = LocalDateTime.of(2014, Month.NOVEMBER, 25, 10, 23);  

 long horas = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(t1, t2);  
 System.out.println(horas);  

 long horas2 = t1.until(t2, ChronoUnit.HOURS);  
 System.out.println(horas2);  

 long horas3 = Duration.between(t1, t2).toHours();  
 System.out.println(horas3);
```

Pelo que está na documentação, o `horas2` e o `horas3` são equivalentes, porém, fiquei em dúvida do primeiro modo. É correto?

Comment: Só para questão de conhecimento, o próprio método `HOURS.between(t1, t2)` equivale à `t1.until(t2, ChronoUnit.HOURS)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que as três formas estão corretas e são equivalentes.

No entanto, me parece que as três vão falhar se houverem mudanças referentes a horário de verão ou mudança de fuso horário.

Comment: Sim, parece que o `LocalDateTime` não tem suporte à `time-zone`, então... Eu executei o trecho de código e aqui deu o mesmo resultado. Diferença sempre de duas horas.